# contour integration of log.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking at a contour integration of the following function:

$f(z)=\frac{z\log(z)}{1-z^2}$ for $z\ne 1$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $z=1$.

I should find the real part of the integral of $f$ in the first quadrant, namely that $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$.

I first found the poles, which are $z=\pm 1$, since $z=-1$ is not in the above area, I only concerned myself my $z=1$, by applying L'Hospital rule, I found that the residual of $f(z)$ is $\frac{-1}{2}$.

Therefore I found the contour integral to be:

$I_c=2\pi\cdot i\cdot (-1/2)=-\pi\cdot i$. Which then has a zero real part.

I think this is wrong, does anybody how what I did wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Integral about what contour?

Comment: The task is to evaluate the above stated function in the first quadrant, It is further defined that z=exp(i*t), where t runs from 0 to pi/2

Comment: so you with to evaluate $\int_C \frac{z\log(z)}{1-z^2}dz$, where $C=\{e^{it}:0\le t \le \pi/2\}$ ? (assuming we have redefined the integrand to achieve continuity, as you do in your post)

Comment: Yes exactly, I am new to complex integration, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Thank you, I see, what are the criterias that allow use of poles and residues for integration?

Comment: Note that there may be simpler ways to solve this than in my answer, but when threw the parameterized form in Wolfram Alpha and saw $-\frac{\pi^2}{16}$ the connection to the basel problem became obvious. At some point you'll inevitably end up using the basel problem, or else you'll have proved the basel problem in the course of your proof! (a decent undertaking)

Answer (score 1):

There is no pole at $1$. $1$ is a removable singularity since $\frac {z \log z} {1-z^{2}} \to -\frac 1 2 $ as $\to 1$.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have not told us what the contour is which means you have not stated your question in a way we can understand.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have the complex plane in R^2 and we are removing (Re(z)<=0 and Im(z)=0) from it. Define this area as D. I further assume that |Im log (z)|<pi. Then I define f(z) as stated above. Inside D, I define a path called C which is given as z=exp(it) for t=0..Pi/2. I now want to integrate f(z) over this path C. This is where I am struggling

Comment: Since your path is not a closed contour you cannot evaluate the integral using poles and residues. You have to evaluate it directly by writing down the definition of integral of $f$ over $C$.

Comment: How would that be possible then? How can I integrate over the complex surface?

Comment: The definition is: $\int_C f(z) \, dz=\int_0^{\pi /2} f(e^{it}) ie^{it}\, dt$.

Comment: Thank you, I see, what are the criterias that allow use of poles and residues for integration?

Comment: @JonathanKiersch integrating an analytic function on a closed contour.

Comment: I see, wouldn't there come a minus in front of the integral above? Or does there apply another rule?

Comment: @JonathanKiersch not sure where you would get a negative sign. We simply let $z=e^{it}$ and note $dz = i e^{it} dt$ since $\frac{dz}{dt} = i e^{it}$

Comment: You have the minus in the integration below, but not in the above, I assume that the below is correct then?

Comment: @JonathanKiersch the negative comes from the logarithm. Note $\frac{z \log(z)}{1-z^2} dz = \frac{e^{it} \log(e^{it})}{1-e^{2it}} (ie^{it}dt) = \frac{e^{it} (it)}{1-e^{2it}} (ie^{it}dt) = \frac{-te^{2it} }{1-e^{2it}}dt$. I used the exact formula Kavi gave above.

Comment: But when you let u=exp(2it), how do you get the minus in front of the 1/4 then dosent that disappear?

Answer (score 0):

We can parameterize:
$$\begin{align*}
&\text{Re}\!\int_C \frac{z\log(z)}{1-z^2}dz \\
&= -\text{Re}\!\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{te^{2it}}{1-e^{2it}}dt&\text{(parameterize)}\\
&= -\frac{1}{4}\text{Re}\!\int_{C'}\frac{\log(z)}{1-z}dz&\text{(let } u=e^{2it}\text{)} \\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\text{Re}\!\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{1}^{-1}\log(z)z^kdz&\text{(geometric series)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\text{Re}\!\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(-i\pi\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)dz&\log(z)\to-t\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\text{Re}\!\left(-i\pi\log(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)&\text{(basel problem)}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\\
\end{align*}$$